# Pandas dataframe generate column with different row info, but no apply function

Tags: python, pandas

maybe question name is not accurate (sorry for that because I don't find any accurate word to describe my question...), let me make an example:

The following dataframe is income with "week_id" and "user_id":

```
week_id  user income 
1        1    100
1        2    50
2        1    200
2        2    30
2        3    150
3        1    100
3        2    150
....
```

I want to add a new column, which contains "income" of previous week, looks like:

```
week_id  user income previous_week_income
1        1    100    0
1        2    50     0
2        1    200    100
2        2    30     50
2        3    150    0
3        1    100    200
3        2    150    30
....
```

It looks like to generate new column with information from other rows, other than current row.

I know solution with apply function, but as it's row by row, it seems to be too slow for my case ( origin dataframe may be tens of millions of rows ), I wonder other fast solution to get the result?

The background is to generate factor for predictive analysis, so I want to use previous week income as one variable when predict current week income.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) if each `week_id` has unique `users`:

```
df['previous_week_income'] = df.groupby('user')['income'].shift().fillna(0)
print (df)
   week_id  user  income  previous_week_income
0        1     1     100                   0.0
1        1     2      50                   0.0
2        2     1     200                 100.0
3        2     2      30                  50.0
4        2     3     150                   0.0
5        3     1     100                 200.0
6        3     2     150                  30.0
```

Comment: Thank you. Glad can help you.